# How do you set the background image of a form to a user-selected image?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) form, and I want the user to select the background image. That is, when the application starts the file dialog appears from where the user can select the image he/she wants as the background.

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is a file dialog class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx) which you can use to ask the user to select an image. Then you can set the forms `BackgroundImage' property.

Comment: @havok: If you make this an answer instead of a comment, it can be marked as 'the answer' and closed.

Comment: @John: Thanks. I'm always a bit wary when not providing a direct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on havok's answer, if you set `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized` and `ShowInTaskbar = false` during form initialization, you can display the dialog in a `Form.Load` event handler ("occurs before a form is displayed for the first time").  The user will see the dialog before the main form is noticeable at all.  After retrieving the image, set the `BackgroundImage` property as havok said, and restore the form to a normal startup state.  `System.Drawing.Image` has a static method `FromFile()` that might help you, too.

Answer (score 2):

There is a file dialog class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx which you can use to ask the user to select an image. Then you can set the forms `BackgroundImage` property.

Comment: Can you include some working code in your answer? For example, exactly how is the file name path being connected to the BackgroundImage property? Is it something like ".BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(FD.FileName);"? What file formats are supported (BMP, GIF, PNG, JPEG, etc.)?